# Coq: Unify with a pattern and get the result

Tags: coq, unification

I want to do `change t with (f _)`, where `t` is a term and `f` is a function, but `change` does not allow placeholders in its second parameter. So I want to write a tactic that unifies `t` and `(f _)` and returns the result `(f x)`, so I can `change t with (f x)`. I know that `t = f _` can be unified by reflexivity, but this approach adds redundancy to the proof term. Is there a nice way to do this task?

Comment: Hello, welcome to PASE! 

Comment: @ice1000 I have been here for a long time, but didn't find anything I could contribute until then.

Answer (score 2):

The following tactic unifies `term` with `pattern` and returns the result.

```ml
Ltac unify_to term pattern :=
  let eq_proof := constr:(eq_refl : term = pattern) in
  match type of eq_proof with
  | _ = ?result => result
  end.
```

Then we can use

```ml
let u := unify_to t uconstr:(f _) in
...
```

to get `u = f x`.